# send multipart with files using retrofit:2.0.0-beta1

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit, multipartform-data

I have problem with sending multipartRequest to server.

```
RequestBody file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), myFile);
        return apiService.updateProfile2(token, file);


@Multipart
@POST("/profile/update")
Call<RegistrationResponse> updateProfile2(@Header(value = "X-AUTH-TOKEN") String toke, @Part(value = "json") RequestBody json);
```

**problem:**

request body is empty, when it come to server

Comment: Did you try with `TypedFile` ?

Comment: @RethinavelPillai there is no TypedFile in Retrofit 2.0

Comment: retrofit:2.0.0-beta1 did not support TypedFile =(

Comment: Can you post the request code ?

Comment: @Anderson C Silva You mean this  Call<RegistrationResponse> call = dataProvider.requestUpdateProfile2(token, new File(path));

Comment: Why do you are trying send "application/json" as Multpartfile ?

Answer (score 1):

## Update

[Uploading files with Retorfit 2 and Multipart](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server)

## Original, off-topic answer

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically
Here is a good article with code that sends multipart. This worked for me.

```
MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(requestURL, charset);

multipart.addHeaderField("User-Agent", "CodeJava");
multipart.addHeaderField("Test-Header", "Header-Value");

multipart.addFormField("description", "Cool Pictures");
multipart.addFormField("keywords", "Java,upload,Spring");

multipart.addFilePart("fileUpload", uploadFile1);
multipart.addFilePart("fileUpload", uploadFile2);

List<String> response = multipart.finish();

System.out.println("SERVER REPLIED:");

for (String line : response) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: But it is not using Retrofit 2.0.0-beta1.

Comment: Thank you! But I need only Retrfil, and version is 2.0.0 -beta1!

Answer (score 0):

First all, do you are trying send the mediaType "application/json" as @Multpart, if you want send the multpartfile so do you needs change somethings in your code.

Something like this:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/profile/update")
    Call<RegistrationResponse> updateProfile2(
    @Header(value = "X-AUTH-TOKEN") String toke,
    @Part("myfile\"; filename=\"image.png\" ") RequestBody file);
```

And change call method to this:

```
RequestBody file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), myFile);
        return apiService.updateProfile2(token, file);
```